# Neron-Severi group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, neron-severi-group

Given a projective variety over a field $k$, the N'eron-Severi group scheme $NS$ is defined to be $Pic_X / Pic_{X,red}^0$ the quotient of the Picard scheme by the reduced scheme of its connected component. It is a classical result that $NS(k)$ is a finitely generated abelian group as an abstract group. I'm wondering if $NS$ as a commutative group scheme over $k$ is a locally constant finitely generated abelian group (by locally, I mean with respect to fppf topology).

Comment: The way you defined it, all nilpotents of $\mathbf{Pic}_X$ will still exist in $\mathbf{NS}_X$, since you only divide by $(\mathbf{Pic}^0_X)^{\operatorname{red}}$. If instead you divide by the full $\mathbf{Pic}^0_X$, then the quotient will have trivial tangent space at $0$, hence be an étale group scheme, so becomes constant when you pass to the algebraic closure.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, you're right. But is it true that $NS$ (my version) ,after base field extension,  is either constant or a product of constant, $\alpha_p$ and $\mu_p$?

Comment: I think it should still split as a product of its component group (étale) and its reduced identity component (local). But it's not true that a local group scheme is a product of $\alpha_{p^i}$ and $\mu_{p^i}$; for example, the $p$-torsion of a supersingular elliptic curve is a non-split extension of $\alpha_p$ with itself.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks! I should've said "iterated extension" instead of "product". It seems true that a local group scheme is an iterated extension of $\alpha_{p^i}$ and $\mu_{p^i)$, right?

Comment: That sounds right (over an algebraically closed field).